# TCP connection issue through firewall

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

i'm confused about TCP connection through firewall.
Source Port(client) is 12345 and dest port(server) is 1433.
At the begining, client successfully sends the request to server from 12345 to 1433. When server sending back, does the client require to open port 12345 in Firewall? 
If yes, it's hard to configure all ports since source port is dynamic.

Best Regards,
Tom

Comment: TCP is a stateful protocol. A router tracks the state of a connection when it is established and automatically opens the return path.

Answer (score 0):

> When server sending back, does the client require to open port 12345 in Firewall?

No. If the client's firewall permitted the outbound connection, it will permit the return traffic.

> If yes, it's hard to configure all ports since source port is dynamic.

Impossible, actually.

Of course there are always ways to *mis*-configure firewalls ...